# Pick the highest group/category for each person - python

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with three columns, Name, group1 and group2. The 'Name' column shows the different people/cases and both the 'group' columns shows the category these people belong too.
Below is an image of how this data set looks:

[image]

As we can see from the above data set, the same person can be assigned to multiple groups and I need to pick the highest group they belong too. 01_high being the highest group and 03_low being the lowest group.

As an example, lets take the first case 'Tom', in group1 he belongs to '01_high' and for group 2 'Tom' belongs to '03_low'. I need to create a third group column 'group3' with the higher category. In this case the value in the group3 column for 'Tom' will be '01_high'.

Code to create the data set:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick','Jack', 'Ann'],
        'group1': ['01_high', '02_medium', '03_low' , '02_medium'],
        'group2':['03_low', '03_low', '02_medium', '03_low']}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Final desired output:

[image]

I'm fairly new to python and not sure how to achieve the desired output so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does it mean by higher group? Does it mean the first group in your data or is there a specific condition / logic to pick the higher group a member belongs to? If it is just based on the sequence of appearance in your data then using drop_duplicates will be enough.

Comment: `out = df.groupby("Name", as_index=False, sort=False).first()` ?

Comment: There was a little confusion with the way I asked the question so made some edits and now it should be clear.

Comment: @Timeless, your code is helpful but the problem with it is that it assumes the first value is always the higher group. However, that's not always the case

Comment: I see that you updated your question but you forgot to do so with the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. Can you *double-check*, please ?

Comment: @Timeless you're absolutory right, I have updated it now. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option :

```
df["group3"] = df.filter(like="group").apply(sorted, axis=1).str[0]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   Name     group1     group2     group3
0   Tom    01_high     03_low    01_high
1  Nick  02_medium     03_low  02_medium
2  Jack     03_low  02_medium  02_medium
3   Ann  02_medium     03_low  02_medium
```

Comment: Perfect! this works and gives me what I was after. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like groupby: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: @Timeless suggested the same but I don't think it works in my case. Happy to be shown if it works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).